# WPF transparent window with alpha channel

Tags: algorithm, ffmpeg, video-capture

I have a wpf transparent window I would like to capture it with alpha channel using ffmpeg or any other algorithm. I have searched more but I could not find clear answer. I am newbie for this algorithm. Can I do this or not. Thank you in advance

Comment: Not [directly](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/19633/1871), AFAIK.

Comment: @Mulvya I read that post but it's answer is not clear. Please tell me algorithm.